# What is the correct format to use Unique in _sql_constraints in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have tried unique in sql_constaints in OpenERP(Odoo) using two different methods using flower brackets {} or square brackets [].
Both works fine.
Which one is correct?

```py
_sql_constraints = {
    ('email_uniq', 'unique(email)', ' Please enter Unique Email id.')
    }
```

(or)

```py
_sql_constraints = [
    ('email_uniq', 'unique(email)', ' Please enter Unique Email id.')
    ]
```

P.S: But if I want to use more than a constraint it accepting only square brackets [] like this example.

```py
_sql_constraints = [
    ('email_uniq', 'unique(email)', ' Please enter Unique Email id.'),
    ('contact_uniq', 'unique(contact)', ' Please enter Unique Mobile no.')
    ]
```

What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct one is square brackets syntax.

1. you can grep on `_sql_constraints` and see it is what is always used,
2. in the ORM code in `openerp/models.py` we can see that the default value is an empty list:

```py
    _sql_constraints = []
    #...
        cls._local_sql_constraints = cls.__dict__.get('_sql_constraints', [])
```

3. in [Odoo 8.0 documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model._constraints) it is said:

> list of `(name, sql_definition, message)` triples defining SQL constraints to execute when generating the backing table.

In python2 you can get a [list](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) with the syntax `[]`.

The syntax `{}` either creates:

- a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) if it is empty `{}` or if there is keys values like this: `{'keyA': 'valueA', 'keyB': 'valueB'}`,
- as of python 2.7 a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) if instantiated like this: `{'value1', 'valueB', 42}`

Comment: But it creates _sql_constraints when I use {} . Even for multiple constraints.

Comment: @ea- +1 for Nice explanation!

Comment: @TintuMon it may work by luck currently in core odoo. A list and a set can often be used interchangeably in python. Using a set you would gain no advantage, and you could get an error with a futur change in Odoo or with an external module which may expect the sql constraint list to be be a _list_.

Comment: Thank you @AtulArvind I"ll follow this in future to avoid error.

Answer (score 5):

In odoo the syntax for sql constraint is list of `(name, sql_definition, message)`. for example

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('name_uniq', 'unique(name)', 'Custom Warning Message'),
    ('contact_uniq', 'unique(contact)', 'Custom Warning Message')
]
```

you can give more then one sql constraint in list of tuples.

when you define a dictionary with out key & value python treat it as set. and set can be itrable.